# How to check datetime in EST in conditional statement in Logic App

Tags: azure, conditional-statements, datetime-format, azure-logic-apps

I have a logic app which runs every half an hour each day. A typical day starts from 3am to 2:59am. So in the condition I have to check whether the current time (EST time) is between 12am to 2:59am and according to the expression evaluation, I execute an action.

My condition expression is as below--

convertTimeZone(utcNow(),'UTC','Eastern Standard Time')

[image: Condition Evaluation]

What's happening now is, even if EST time is 12:30am it still evaluates to False. But, It should evaluate to true as 12:30 am is in between 12:00am and 2:59am.

What wrong am I doing here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please use this expression in your condition action:

```
convertTimeZone(utcNow(),'UTC','Eastern Standard Time','HH:mm:ss')
```

I did a test and it works well.

[image]